# Regular expression to match group of consecutive characters

Tags: javascript, regex

I need a JS expression to match a combination of /* characters

I have this now

```
/(\b\/*\b)g
```

but it does not work.

ETA:
any string that has /* should match

so...

- Hello      NO MATCH
- 123        NO MATCH
- /* HELLo   MATCH
- /*4534534  MATCH

Comment: You can use: `/\/\*/g` but you should add valid/invalid matches in question.

Comment: Please give expected IO

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "a combination of /* characters"? Please provide an example of your input and expected output/match.

Comment: just did. Any time the exact combo of forward slash followed by star is occutring, it will be a match

Comment: Does the `/*` itself need to be included in the match, or do you only want the characters that follow it?

Comment: @ anubhava  doesn't work

Comment: What do you mean by _combination of /* characters_?

Comment: does the /* has to in the beginning?

Comment: @CAusting - I need to match /* in the string.

Comment: [It sure works in this demo](https://regex101.com/r/JzZD7h/1)

Comment: @Sebastian Speitel no, anywhere in the string

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/AOiigU/1 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might use a positive lookahead and test if the string contains `/*`?

If so, match any character one or more times `.+` from the beginning of the string `^` until the end of the string `$`

[`^(?=.*\/\*).+$`](https://regex101.com/r/GY1p8J/1)

**Explanation**

- `^` Begin of the string
- `(?=` Positive lookahead that asserts what is on the right

  - `.*\/\*` Match any character zero or more time and then `/*`
- `)` Close positive lookahead
- `.+` Match any character one or more times
- `$` End of the string

```js
const strings = [
  "Hello NO MATCH",
  "123 NO MATCH",
  "/* HELLo MATCH",
  "/*4534534 MATCH",
  "test(((*/*"
];
let pattern = /^(?=.*\/\*).+$/;

strings.forEach((s) => {
  console.log(s + " ==> " + pattern.test(s));
});
```

I think you could also use [indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) to get the index of the first occurence of `/*`. It will return -1 if the value is not found.

```js
const strings = [
  "Hello NO MATCH",
  "123 NO MATCH",
  "/* HELLo MATCH",
  "/*4534534 MATCH",
  "test(((*/*test",
  "test /",
  "test *",
  "test /*",
  "/*"
];
let pattern = /^(?=.*\/\*).+$/;

strings.forEach((s) => {
  console.log(s + " ==> " + pattern.test(s));
  console.log(s + " ==> " + (s.indexOf("/*") !== -1));
});
```

Comment: Thank you, worked

Answer (score 1):

Since you only want to detect if it contains something you don't have to use regex and can just use `.includes("/*")`:

```js
function fits(str) {
  return str.includes("/*");
}

var test = [
  "Hello NO MATCH",
  "123 NO MATCH",
  "/* HELLo MATCH",
  "/*4534534 MATCH"
];

var result = test.map(str => fits(str));
console.log(result);
```